# MTB Helmet on a Road-Touring Cube bike

Tags: helmets, touring-bikes

I'm getting the next month a Cube Nuroad black/red 2018 for my little trips and some commuting.

[image]

I got and old Btwin MTB helmet bought in Spain. Is it good to wear on this type of bike?

[image]

I'd use this bike for some gravel terrain, long trips and commuting.

Thanks!

Comment: Just want to note that using an MTB helmet on a road bike would decrease your style points in the eyes of roadies. If you plan to join riding groups, this is something of a concern. If you only do commute and solo raids, then you could not care less about their weird fashion police.

Comment: Does the MTB helmet meet the legal requirements for the jurisdiction you ride? If not, is it ever going to be a problem (e.g. medical insurance declined after a prang because of it)

Comment: @mattnz I think is enough for daily riding and touring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The helmet itself will work fine.

On a road bike like the one you posted a photo of, your head and shoulders are usually a lot lower than on a mountain bike.  The visor on the helmet may block your forward vision because of that.  Or you may wind up having to force yourself to hold your head higher than is natural, which might be very tiring on your neck.  If so, just take the visor off.  It looks to have bolts/screws holding it on, so it's probably designed to be removed.

One comment:  that helmet doesn't appear to be very well ventilated.  If you do long rides when it's hot, that may be bothersome.  Then again, if you commute year-round, that may be very useful when it's cold.

Comment: Good answer. I'd add that if the helmet is old (as the OP states), replacing it should be considered. >5 years, or if it's dinged and dented, go ahead a replace.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure your helmet would provide adequate protection in principle.  Fundamentally, the job of a helmet is the same, whatever kind of bike you're riding. However, my suspicion is that this helmet won't work on a road bike because of the body posture while riding.

On a road bike, your back is much more horizontal than it is on a mountain bike, which means you must lift your head to see forwards. However, the visor of your helmet is likely to block your forward view. It's probably removable, in which case this wouldn't be an issue. What looks like a bigger issue to me is that your helmet comes a long way down the back of your head. This would make it difficult to lift your head to see forwards.

You also say that the helmet is "old" so, honestly, it's probably a good idea to buy a new one anyway. The materials degrade over time so old helmets offer less protection.

Comment: Spot on. My spare helmet has a visor and is a pain in the neck on the tourer (literally so after only an hour). My main helmet is a commute/mountain/general purpose helmet with no visor.

Comment: I tried to get off the visor and almost break the helmet. I'll give this to my wife and look for another road/gravel helmet for me.